# Creating a list using data from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, list, display

I'm trying to create a basic product list that takes data from the MySQL database and display on screen of the website.

I currently have the following code but still needs some work, it currently only displays the name and category with an error message saying:Warning: printf(): Too few arguments in C:\xampp\htdocs\ICTDBS504\list items.php on line 41
() ()

I also need to add a photo in but I am unsure on how and where that goes in the code. Should the photo be apart of the html or saved on the database? and if on the database how does that get written into the php code

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "etrading");

    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    $query = "SELECT Name, Category, Price, Duration, Photo FROM item ORDER by ItemID LIMIT 3";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    /* numeric array */
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);

    /* associative array */
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    printf ("%s (%s) (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["Category"]);

    /* associative and numeric array */
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    printf ("%s (%s) (%s)\n", $row[0], $row["Price"], $row["Duration"]);

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: in associative array you have there placeholder for printf and only two params so this is why it is throwing error.

Comment: Line `printf ("%s (%s) (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["Category"]);` wants three fields, there are only 2.

Comment: For the image part: Save the image in a folder on your webserver. Then simply save the name of the picture in your database. After that you can simply get the name from the database, and add it in something like `echo'<img src="some/folders/'.$row["picturename"].'">';`

Comment: i think the help you can get is mentioned by me & @NigelRen th.and you have to write the rest of code yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part of your code you have type more arguments in `printf()`:

```
    /* associative array */
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    printf ("%s (%s) (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["Category"]);
```

`Printf` have 3 arguments but you only have put 2: `$row["Name"]` and `$row["Category"]`.

To solve the error you have to fix the arguments or add 1 more datas.

Comment: Ermm. '4 arguments'?

Comment: sorry, params, i will change it. Thanks

Comment: ups, i am asleep yet :(

Comment: awesome thanks. now it appears like this 
Black Hat (Clothes) () () () why does the price and duration not appear? is it because they are saved as date and decimal?